# Can't use JSONObject in Google App Engine (Java) anymore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Half an hour ago I opened Eclipse to edit a Google App Engine app, previously everything was working fine, no errors, I haven't updated anything (at least not knowingly).

I had imported: `com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject`
without error, however now I get this error:

`use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning`

It has never broken before, it came with the Google App Engine download for Eclipse, why has it suddenly started now? And how can I get rid of it? (they change I was making was very small and quick, it would be nice not to have to use a different JSON library)

Comment: It seems repackaged is not supported with the version of GAE you have, you may need to try another supported JSonObject API.

Comment: @thinksteep, as far as I know I haven't changed version, how I can make it support it?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/562b50bd40e8c2f7   Here is some discussion may be useful.

Comment: @thinksteep, yes I'd seen that, it's specific to base64.

Comment: I posted a similar issue on the google groups list, but for another jar, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine-java/google$20sql$20warning/google-appengine-java/ar9-Ho8dIyA/5L6eIC29DTsJ . In practice, the app works fine after deploying.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: I think you mean Koma!!!

Answer (score 8):

`com.google.appengine.repackaged.*` contains internal classes that should not be used by application code.

`org.json` is implemented by [many libraries](http://www.json.org/), for example [JSON-Java](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java). Simply include one of them in your GAE project.

Answer (score 4):

AppEngine 1.8.4 use

com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject

Comment: I don't get any warnings about the use of JSONObject provided in this package. Is it likely to be modified or removed as well?

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to have to figure this all out from first principles, here is a step-by-step:

1. Get the sources from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java (you can download the zip, use Git, etc.)
2. Make a directory in your project json/org/json and put the sources in there.
3. Use "Refresh" in Eclipse so that it sees and compiles the directory.
4. Change all the "import com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.xxx;" to "import org.json.xxx;" in your code

Unfortunately this adds a whole lot of Warnings, but they do seem to be harmless.

Comment: Good advice, but don't forget to add that folder to 'Source' under build properties.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of **Use of com.google.appengine.repackaged may result in your app breaking without warning.** error simple declare your class with **full package name**. It solves your problem.

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.JsonObject jsonObject = 
new com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.JsonObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing my import to com.google.gson.Gson worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Package **com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson** has been deprecated on the latest appengine version. Therefore the following statements

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
...
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

will you give you the following error in your appgengine logs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/gson/JsonElement
```

You need to use the new Json library instead:

1) add new dependency to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

2) replace

```
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

with

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```